# What is the Koran/Quran/Qur'an's stance on religious freedom?

Tags: quran, freedom-of-belief, freedom

Are there any verses in the Koran/Quran/Qur'an's that speak about religious freedom? If so, which themes are given? And what are these verses?

Comment: Questions of the form "Tell me everything Islam says about [topic]" tend to be far too broad to reasonably answer here. I would strongly recommend you check the advice in our help centre pages on [ask] and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) to better understand the sorts of questions we do encourage here.